# Telerik Rad Grid View Header space

Tags: wpf, silverlight, telerik, telerik-grid

In our current project we are using telerik rad controls for developing silverlight project, 
according to logged-in user the columns are displayed on the datagrid, for some of the users some grid columns are set to invisible, which is leading to a gap between columns ,when the user is logged-in the space between the columns does not look good, 
does any one know how to fix this gap, thank you very much.

we are using a converter,

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastQtyNotAvail}" Width="150" IsVisible="{Binding IsColumnVisibleToCustomer, Source={StaticResource PFOViewModel}}" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Right" HeaderTextAlignment="Center"/> 

public bool IsColumnVisibleToCustomer
 {get
 { 
   return !WebContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Customer");
 }
} public bool IsInRole(string role) { if ((this.Roles == null)) { return false; } return global::System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(this.Roles, role); 
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the columns to be invisible? Have you tried removing the columns instead of hiding them? Would you mind posting some code?

Comment: I updated the code, i m trying to show all the 20 columns to the main user and only 10 columns to the customer, so is there any other way other than using isvisible, visibilty, and removing the columns, thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off handling the AutoGeneratingColumns event of the RadGridView. You can then cancel generation of columns according to whatever conditions you imagine.

[The Telerik documentation will give you as good a sample as I can](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-prevent-column-autogenerate.html)

If you dont use AutoGeneration of columns, then try removing columns in the Loaded Event (of the grid) instead.

Something like:

```
void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGridView grid = sender as RadGridView;
    var remove = ((IEnumerable<GridViewDataColumn>)grid.Columns).FirstOrDefault(o => o.UniqueName == "PropertyName");
    if (remove != null)
    {
        grid.Columns.Remove(remove);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked for me, I made the code changes as I have multiple columns to be removed, the code looks like this RadGridView grid = sender as RadGridView;          List<GridViewColumn> columnListnew = new List<GridViewColumn>();
    var column0 = grdProducts.Columns["WeeklyUsage"];
     columnListnew.Add( column0 );                               foreach(var column in columnListnew)
    {
       grdProducts.Columns.Remove(column);
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would use some jQuery to check the number of columns in the grid and set padding or margins based on that.  My guess is the columns are still there with no content, so you could also remove those using jQuery. Just check if the $("#column").html() == ""

Comment: I updated the code can you please take a look at it and let me know.. thank you for your help..